# Java IS-A relationship with method override

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("A m1");
    }
}

public class B extends A {

public void m1() {
    System.out.println("B m1");
}

public void m2() {
    System.out.println("B m2");
}
```

}

```
public class Result {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*A a = new A();
    a.m1();

    B b = new B();
    b.m1();
    b.m2();
    */
    A ab = new B();
    ab.m1();
}
```

}

In the above code, I have a Class A and Class B that extends Class A. In class C I am creating the object of class B and it's been assigned to class A. when I try to call ab.m1() it calling the method in class B.but when I try to call ab.m2() i get compile time error. I am not understanding why class B method is called during ab.m1(). can someone help me in understanding the concept much better.thanks in advance.

Comment: `.m2()` does not exists on references to class `A` only on instances of `B` that are assigned to a reference to `B`. So `ab` is an instance of `A` which does not have the method `.m2()`. Your IDE should show you this very clearly. If you typed `ab.` it should only show you methods from `A`. `B` is an `A` but not the other way around. `A` has no knowledge of `B` or what it provides.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome This is not a duplicate of that question. The one you linked to has a terribly broad title and some specific questions in the body. It should not be used as a dupe target.

Comment: Both the questions is about inheritance but my problem is different from what is being asked in that question.

Comment: ["*A pox on the ISA relationship. It’s been misleading and damaging for decades. Inheritance is not ISA. Inheritance is the redeclaration of functions and variables in a sub-scope. No more. No less.*" -- Robert Cecil Martin](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/#comment-436689)

Comment: Are you asking why `B`'s `m1()` method is called instead of `A`'s `m1()`? If so, since `ab` is an instance of class `B`, its `m1()` method takes precedence and overrides all of its parent class' `m1()` methods. In the same way all objects have a `toString()` method because the `Object` class has a `toString()` method, but any implementation in the lower classes overrides it.

Comment: `[teach-me]` You're asking the compiler to find method `m2` *via eference* to class `A`. Compiler tells you that instances of class A don't have `m2`.  And compiler is right. There are at least SOME instances of `A` that don't have `m2` - those that are not instances of `B`. You think that compiler remembers that `ab` was assigned an instance of `B`, but it's not the case. All it knows is that you have "some sort" of `A`: could be `A`, could be some unknown `C`. The only thing to go on is what's available in `A` itself. Oh, and yes - the inheritance is most often the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Nordii will it check m1() of class A? If an is an instance of class B then it should call m2() also

Answer (score 1):

```
A ab = new B();
```

You create a *reference* of type A and point it to an *object* of type B. This is valid and legal because B extends A, so an object of type B IS-A type A. That's why, when you call `ab.m1();` you're calling the method defined in B. Your object type is B, so it overrides the method defined in A.

However, you can't call `ab.m2()` because the *reference* is type A, and knows nothing about new methods defined in B that weren't included in A. The reference only has access to the things defined in A (and anything that it might inherit from its super types, like Object).

Comment: So should I consider object type or reference type?

Comment: @KeerthiPrasad The code you showed is a perfect example of why you need to consider both. You have both a reference and an object, and the types of both make a difference in how your code works.

Answer (score -1):

```
B -->A// B is-a A
A ab = new B()//object of B is created and reference variable is type of Super type as A is super class of B
```

since `ab.m1()` is type of A class and can be accessible through super variable.
`ab.m2()` is type of B class and can not be accessed using super type reference, thats where down casting comes into picture.

try:

```
B a = (B)ab;// down casting
a.m1();
a.m2();
```

now you call both method of B class.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not worried about down casting, I am looking how the object creation and reference type work so that respective methods being called.

Comment: @KeerthiPrasad look at the Inheritance B extend A that mean B have all the member of its super class except private and final. `A ab = new B()` means Object of B is created and reference `ab` is type of super class i,e A which point to B object. using `ab` we can not call any sub class method or variable becoz super class is not aware of anything in sub class.